# Add up django fields from several models

Tags: django, django-queryset

My application has several post types, each post type is a single model, each of these models has a field called "up_vote" and "down_vote". Now i want to display the user a add-up of all those  fields, so that i calculate request.user.model1.up_vote + request.user.model2.up_vote + request.user.model3.up_vote and same for down_vote.

But i dont know how the query has to look like at my views.
In the end i only want to display the overall up/down_votes accross all posts the user has created.

models.py

```
# code example

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Title", max_length=30)
    ...
    up_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    down_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Post_Vote(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    voted = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('voter', 'voted')
```

thx for reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) e.g.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

user = User.objects.get(...)
up_vote_count = Post.objects.filter(user=user).aggregate(Sum('up_vote'))
down_vote_count = Post.objects.filter(user=user).aggregate(Sum('down_vote'))
```

Comment: Okay but where to i get my user from? As i want to display the user his total up_vote and total down_votes accross all post types

Comment: You can `filter` over the user before using `aggregate`, check the updated answer

Comment: Ahh okay, i first was trying to use this: Post.objects.annotate(total_up_votes=Count('up_vote', filter=Q(author=user)))
with no sucsess but your seems to work fine, thank you :)